# How to rewrite multiline path into one-line relative path

Tags: shell-script

I've been looking everywhere. Didn't find the answer so I'm looking up to you!

Program in my job outputs many 10-50 `*.pc` files with folder-structure:

```
RESULTS/MODEL_Y0/Positioning_1.pc
RESULTS/MODEL_Y0/SK312_2SK_Y0_2012.pc

RESULTS/MODEL_Y100/Positioning_2.pc
RESULTS/MODEL_Y100/SK312_2SK_Y100_2012.pc

RESULTS/MODEL_Y250/Positioning_45.pc
RESULTS/MODEL_Y250/SK312_2SK_-Y575_2012.pc
```

Each `PC` file has inside absolute paths starting on xxx (not always 101, but it's always the **second** occurance of the `INCLU` word) line like:

```
INCLU / Positioning_1.pc
INCLU / /ST/statika/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/SK312_SERIE.inc
INCLU / /ST/statika/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/SK312_xPL_impactor.inc
INCLU / /ST/statika/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/SK312_materials.inc
```

I need to change these lines of absolute path to relative like:

```
INCLU / Positioning_1.pc
INCLU / ../../SK312_SERIE.inc
INCLU / ../../SK312_xPL_impactor.inc
INCLU / ../../SK312_materials.inc
```

Which I've done by writing a script placed above `RESULTS` folder: (part of the script)

```
grep -rl "${SEARCH}" --include \*.pc ./ | xargs sed -i "s#${SEARCH}#${REPLACE}#g"
```

where:

```
$SEARCH = /ST/statika/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/
$REPLACE = ../../
```

BUT here is the problem. When operating from **longer than 81 chars path**, the program will output the `.pc` files in the same folder-structure pattern, but inside the `PC` file, the absolute paths are separated to new line by `-` on 81. char position:

```
INCLU / Positioning_1.pc
INCLU / /ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2S-
K_xxx/SK312_SERIE.inc
INCLU / /ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2S-
K_xxx/SK312_xPL_impactor.inc
INCLU / /ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2S-
K_xxx/SK312_materials.inc
```

where:

```
$SEARCH = /ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/
```

Here's the problem. My script doesn't see the variable `$SEARCH`. What's even bigger problem is that the path could be longer than 180 chars so there will be three-line path with two `-` dividers.

I can't comprehend how to write a script that would be functional with these multi-lines so that the path variable would shorten to `../../SK312_*.inc` as before with short absolute one-line path.

Comment: Are the line numbers in your actual file?

Comment: Ah, sorry. No they aren't. I wanted to express how the linebreak works. First line starts with `INCLU`, second after the `-` at random position of the absolute path after the 81th minus "INCLU / " so after 73th char of the path.

Comment: Ah, OK. Please [edit] your question and remove them since they are confusing. Could you also show us one of the problem paths? None of the _paths_ you show are more than 81 characters long. Do you mean _lines_ that are more than 81 characters? I also don't understand your output. You said that lines are cut in the output of your command but the cut lines you show still have the original path, not the modified one. Finally, please also tell us your operating system since this sort of thing can depend on the versions and implemetations of the standard tools you are using.

Comment: Line-numbers removed.
The problem paths are there. :-)
`/ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/SK312_SERIE.inc`
was split to 2 lines:
`/ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2S-` & 
`K_xxx/SK312_SERIE.inc`
In the `PC` file the 81 char line is:
`INCLU / /ST/statika/uziv/JVERNER/PROJEKTY/Ansa/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2S-` (with the `INCLU / `)

Comment: The program I use is outputting two kind of `PC` files relative on the working directory. 1st kind - with lines less than 81 chars long: `INCLU / /ST/statika/AGP-Pedestrian_Ansa-Meta/SK312_2SK_xxx/SK312_SERIE.inc` and the 2nd kind - with lines longer than 81 chars long separated into two lines and divided by `-` on the 81st char of the first line. I **have to** use Linux: OpenSuse 12.2 and every tool that is installed by default. My script has to work on all computers in my company.

Comment: You can join splitted lines before check|exchage path `sed -i "/-$/N;s/-\n//;s#${SEARCH}#${REPLACE}#" *.pc`

Comment: That's IT! Oh you clever man! Many many thanks! There is only one question left. I'm using your command in `for d in $directories ... for f in $files; do ... your command` so that it would apply on *.pc file in directory I'm working on. But is there a way to write it so that it will look in sub/sub directories into every *.pc file and do the change? So that I won't need do the loop? And many thanks again! Write it like an answer so I can approve it!

Comment: (I was doing this with command grep `grep -rl "${SEARCH}" --include \*.pc ./ | xargs sed -i "s#${SEARCH}#${REPLACE}#g"` but that's not working anymore because of the multiline. Would be possible to use the "join-splitted-lines" on grep too so I can show on screen in which files were these lines found?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your program is cutting the lines, you will need to join them before running your `sed`. For example:

```
grep -rl "${SEARCH}" --include \*.pc ./ | 
    xargs sed -i "s/-$//; s/-\n//; s#${SEARCH}#${REPLACE}#g"
```

Or

```
grep -rl "${SEARCH}" --include \*.pc ./ |
    xargs perl -i -pe "s/-\n//; s#$SEARCH#$REPLACE#g"
```

Alternatively, you could use `find` instead of `grep`:

```
find  -type f -name '*.pc' -exec perl -i -pe "s/-\n//; s#$SEARCH#$REPLACE#g" {} +
```

All of the above approaches will recurse into subdirectories.